# Collection element of type 'CFTypeRef _Nullable' (aka 'const void *') is not an Objective-C object

Tags: ios, xcode

I m having a below util method in my project. I did not face any problem in previous versions of iOS 10.

```
+ (CGRect)boundsRectWithSize:(id)objView
{
    return [[objView text] boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake([objView bounds].size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                        options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                     attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : [objView font]}//Issue in this line
                                        context: nil];
}
```

[image]

objView can be of `UIlabel`, `UITextView`, `UItextField`

but in iOS 10 application does not compile with below error

```
Collection element of type 'CFTypeRef _Nullable' (aka 'const void *') is not an Objective-C object
```

Answer (score 2):

First I thought it was a UILabel, so I said to cast it to UILabel in attributes dictionary. But it can be any of type UILabel, UITextView and UITextField as you said. So you can get font first with `valueForKey:` method and then use this font in attributes dictionary.

```
 + (CGRect)boundsRectWithSize:(id)objView
    {
        UIFont *font= (UIFont *)[objView valueForKey:@"font"];
        return [[objView text] boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake([objView bounds].size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                            options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                         attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : font}//Issue in this line
                                            context: nil];
    }
```